# Antenna spec about VSWR and Impedance

Tags: antenna

It's said that impedance is 50 Ohms, and VSWR <2:1. I understand that 50 Ohms mean the input impedance (in that case transmission line or in other words cable)
Does the VSWR < 2:1 mean nominal impedance during the operating bandwidth is betwen 25 and 100 Ohms?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the VSWR < 2:1 mean nominal impedance during the operating bandwidth is between 25 and 100 Ohms?

Yes.

[Return loss calculator](https://chemandy.com/calculators/return-loss-and-mismatch-calculator.htm)